# Google Wifi not working with Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1030

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, 802.11n

I just got a Google Wifi, and almost all our devices connect to the new network fine.  The exception is an old Windows 7 Dell Inspiron N5110 laptop, which sees the network but isn't able to connect.  It has built-in wifi, Centrino Wireless-N 1030.  I tried rebooting and running Windows update, but it still won't connect.

I think the problem might be that Google Wifi supports 802.11n but the old network was 802.11g?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Dell notebook has the same Centrino Wireless-N 1030 Wi-Fi adapter and I can confirm that it does support 802.11n. Besides fallback to 802.11g which will decrease WLAN speed greatly, you can just try disable 802.11n *Channel Bonding* ([see Limitations of 802.11n Channel Bonding](https://www.lifewire.com/get-300-mbps-speed-on-802-11n-network-818267)) by going into Device Manager > Network Adapters > Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1030 > Advanced and setting property "**802.11n Channel Width for band 2.4**" to "**20 MHz Only**".

[image: 802.11n Channel Width for band 2.4 setting.]

Note that this screenshot taken with driver date 2014-01-26

Answer (score 1):

The Centrino Wireless-N 1030 wifi adapter has problems with 802.11n, but you can tell it to fall back to 802.11g by going into Device Manager > Network Adapters > Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1030 > Advanced and setting property "802.11n Mode" to "Disabled".

[image: device manager]